Evaluate: $\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor}i\binom{n-i+1}{i}$
Is there a closed form of the expression
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{\left\lfloor\left(n + 1\right)/2\right\rfloor}
i\binom{n - i + 1}{i}
$$
My Attempt:
From what I observe it is a situation where

there are $n/2$ groups containing
$n, n - 1, n - 2,\ldots,n/2$ persons respectively
and from each group $1,2,3,\ldots,n/2$ persons are chosen
and also a President is selected from these chosen persons.

But I am not able to get a closed form.

The sum is related to A001629. Due to the floor function one needs to adjust for odd values of $n$. The sum is then $\frac{1}{5}\left(\left(2+n\right) F_n+ n F_{2+n}\right)+\frac{1}{4}(-1+(-1)^n)(n+1)$

$\displaystyle n - i + 1 \geq i \implies i \leq {n + 1 \over 2}$. So, you must $\color{red}{\large correct}$ the upper limit.

@Felix Marin. I have edited.

Trying to use a combinatorial interpretation seems difficult, as it requires having an interpretation of $\binom{n+1-i}{i}$, but because the $i$ appears in both the top and the bottom, none of the descriptions I can find are particularly simple (e.g., "pick i out of n+1 people, but none of them are the first i.").  The difficulty is further exemplified by the fact that, if there weren't the factor of $i$ in each summand, the sum would give the Fibonacci numbers (assuming we extend the sum to go as far as it can, there is a mismatch of $n+1$ in the binomial coefficient by $n/2$ in the indexing), which doesn't have a particularly nice direct combinatorial description.
Instead, we can use the identity $\binom{n+1}{k}=\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}$ to get a recursion for the sum.  To simplify notation, we set $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $k<0$ or $k>n$, and then take the sums to be over all possible values of $i$, with the caveat that if $n$ is odd, our version of the sum will have an additional term of $(n+1)/2$.  Set $a_n=\sum i\binom{n-i}{i}$.  Then
$$\begin{align}a_{n+1}&=\sum i\binom{n+1-i}{i} \\
                      &=\sum i\left(\binom{n-i}{i}+\binom{n-i}{i-1}\right) \\
                      &=\sum i\binom{n-i}{i}+\sum i\binom{n-i}{i-1} \\ 
                      &=\sum i\binom{n-i}{i}+\sum ((i-1)+1)\binom{n-((i-1)+1)}{i-1} \\ 
                      &=\sum i\binom{n-i}{i}+\sum (j+1)\binom{n-1-j}{j} \\
                      &=a_n+a_{n-1}+\sum\binom{n-1-j}{j} \\
                      &=a_n+a_{n-1}+f_{n}.
\end{align}$$
This recurrence relation then can then be attacked via other methods, such as generating functions.  There are a number of approaches along  these lines, for example using partial fraction.  Here is an alternative that avoids partial fractions.
If $A(x)=\sum a_n x^n$ and $F(x)=\sum f_n x^n$, where these sums are taken over $n\geq 0$, then with the convention that $f_0=0, f_1=1$, we have $F(x)=\frac{x}{1-x-x^{2}}$ and $A(x)=F(x)^2=\frac{x^2}{(1-x-x^{2})^2}$.
Noting that both $F(x)^2$ and $F'(x)$ will have a denominator of $(1-x-x^2)^2$ suggests expressing $F(x)^2$ in terms of $F'(x)$.  Because we will need a little flexibility, we will set $G(x)=F(x)/x=\frac{1}{1-x-x^2}$ and we will look to express $G(x)^2=\frac{d}{dx}(P(x)G(x))+Q(x)G(x)$ where $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are low degree polynomials.  By using the extended Euclidean algorithm to find that $\frac{4}{5}(1-x-x^2)+\frac{2x+1}{5}(2x+1)=1$, we get
$$\frac{1}{(1-x-x^2)^2}=\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{2x+1}{1-x-x^2}\right)+\frac{2}{1-x-x^2} \right).$$
Writing things in terms of $F(x)$, we have
$$5A(x)=2x^2 F'(x)+x^2\frac{d}{dx}(F(x)/x)+2xF(x).$$
Comparing the $n$th coefficient in each generating function, we get
$$5a_n=2nf_{n-1}+(n-1)f_n=(n+1)f_{n-1}+(n-1)f_{n+1}.$$
Of course, using the Fibonacci recurrence, we can also rewrite this in a number of different ways.  Additionally, the final formula suggests other approaches we might have used.

Not super helpful, but I have thought of a combinatorial interpretation that can get us to $A(x)=F(x)^2$ faster.  It starts with an interpretation of the formula $f_{n+1}=\sum \binom{n-i}{i}$.  We start with the result that $f_{n+1}$ is the number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of $1$s and $2$s.  If there are $i$ $2$s, then there are $n-i$ summands, and we are marking which of those summands are $2$.  By considering that any sum either ends in a $1$ or a $2$, and dropping the final $1$ yields a sum that adds to $n-1$ but dropping a final $2$ yields a sum that adds to $n-2$ shows that this counting problem satisfies the Fibonacci recurrence, and then it is a matter of checking the initial conditions.
With this in mind, how do we interpret $\sum i\binom{n-i}{i}$? Here, we are picking $i$, looking at the number of ways of writing $n$ as a sum of $i$ $2$s and $n-i$ $1$s, but we are also picking one of those $2$s to be marked. This is equivalent to just looking at all possible sums, but with one of the $2$s marked.  With a marked sum, we can look at all the summands that come before the marked $2$ and all the summands that come after the marked $2$.  Thus, marked sums are in bijection with the number of ways to write $n-2=j+k$, and then writing each of $j$ and $k$ as a sum of $1$s and $2$s.  In equations:
$$\begin{align}\sum_i i\binom{n-i}{i}&=\sum_{j+k=n-2} \left( \sum_i \binom{j-i}{i} \right)\left( \sum_i \binom{k-i}{i} \right) \\
&=\sum_{j+k=n-2} f_{j+1}f_{k+1} \\
&= \sum_{j+k=n}f_jf_k \end{align}.$$
This formula leads directly to the generating function equation $A(x)=F(x)^2$.

You are wrong when you say the Fibonacci numbers do not have a nice combinatorial description! $F_{n+1}$ is the number of finite sequences whose entries are all $1$ or $2$ and whose sum is $n$. Alternatively, $F_{n+1}$ is the number of ways to tile an $n\times 1$ rectangle with $1\times 1$ squares and $2\times 1$ dominoes. This combinatorial interpretation leads to proofs of many famous Fibonacci identities: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Combinatorial_proofs

@MikeEarnest I didn't say they didn't have a nice combinatorial description, I said they didn't have a nice direct one, by which I meant that they didn't have one that yields a closed form.

Let $$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} i\binom{n-i}{i}.$$
Your sum is just $S_{n+1}$.
This sum is related to the Fibonacci numbers, $F_n$, defined by  $F_0=0,F_1=1$ and $n\in \mathbb Z\implies F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ . Consider an $n\times 1$ rectangle. It is well-known that the number of ways to tile this rectangle using $1\times 1$ squares and $2\times 1$ dominoes is $F_{n+1}$. Furthermore, the number of tilings which use exactly $i$ dominoes is $\binom{n-i}{i}$. This gives $S_n$ a combinatorial interpretation; $S_n$ is the number of ways to choose a tiling of the board with $i$ dominoes, and then to mark one of the dominoes (this explains the factor of $i$; there are $i$ choices for the domino to mark).
Let us see if we can count these tilings with a single marked domino in a different way, to get a different formula for $S_n$. Instead of choosing a tiling, and then choosing a domino to mark, we could first choose the location of the marked domino, and then choose a tiling consistent with that placement. The marked domino can be placed in any of $n-1$ places, which splits the board into two sections of total width $n-2$. Say these sections have length $k$ and $n-2-k$; the sections can be tiled with squares and dominoes in $F_{k+1}$ and $F_{n-1-k}$ ways, repsectively. Summing over all possible $k$, we get
$$
S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}F_{k+1}F_{n-(k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}F_kF_{n-k}
$$
This formula is also given in OEIS page for $S_n$: https://oeis.org/A001629.

Consider the generating function of the sum:
$$
F(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty i \binom{n-i+1}{i} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty i \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n-i+1}{i} x^n
$$
Using standard expansions $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n-i+1}{i}x^n = \frac{x^{2i-1}}{(1-x)^{i+1}}$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty i x^{i-1} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$, the sum collapses into
$$\begin{align}
F(x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{ix^{2i-1}}{(1-x)^{i+1}} &= \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty i \left(\frac{x^2}{1-x}\right)^{i-1} \\&= \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \frac{1}{(1-\frac{x^2}{1-x})^2} = \frac{x}{(1-x-x^2)^2}.
\end{align}$$
The later is, indeed, the self-convolution of Fibonacci numbers, as their genfunc is $\frac{1}{1-x-x^2}$.

Looking at your last lines, I think you have an issue with the self-convolution because the square of $\frac{1}{(1-x-x^2)^2}$ isn't $\frac{x}{(1-x-x^2)^2}$. I think that it is due to the fact that you begin Fibonacci sequence at index $1$ instead of index $0$.

It's the matter of notation. As far as I understand, the sequence defined in the question starts with $0, 1, 2, 5, 10, \dots$ rather than $0, 0, 1, 2, 5, \dots$, so $\frac{x}{(1-x-x^2)^2}$ is really the self-convolution of $f_0=0, f_1=1$ which has genfunc $\frac{x^2}{(1-x-x^2)^2}$, shifted by one value to the left. Or, equivalently, it is the self-convolution of $f_0=1, f_1=1$, which has genfunc $\frac{1}{(1-x-x^2)^2}$, shifted by one value to the right.
